# Selenium test coverage in jacoco report 0%

Tags: selenium, code-coverage, maven-failsafe-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am trying to get tests runnning with maven failsafe to show up in thwe jacoco report, I have split the unit and integration tests and all my tests pass and the verify runs fine.

I get a created integration test report in my target directory and it always shows zero coverage even though my basic test using selenium does hit some controller functions.

How do I get jacoco to pick up the coverage for the selenium driven tests?

The unit test report is fine and shows me the code coverage so this is just for the selenium tests, I do not get any build issues and the tests do run, they just dont seem to get any coverage reporting.

Below is my failsafe and jacoco pom file snippets and I am running a maven clean verify, I am also using the cargo plugin to run my war file in tomcat and I am using phantom js maven plugin.

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when integration tests are run. -->
                <argLine>${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
                <!-- Skips integration tests if the value of skip.integration.tests 
                    property is true -->
                <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <phantomjs.binary>${phantomjs.binary}</phantomjs.binary>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which 
                    is passed as VM argument when Maven the Surefire plugin is executed. -->
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                        <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                        <!-- Sets the name of the property containing the settings for JaCoCo 
                            runtime agent. -->
                        <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                        <includes>
                            <include>com/test/**</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <!-- Ensures that the code coverage report for unit tests is created 
                    after unit tests have been run. -->
                <execution>
                    <id>post-unit-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                        <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                        <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <!-- Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which 
                    is passed as VM argument when Maven the Failsafe plugin is executed. -->
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                        <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                        <!-- Sets the name of the property containing the settings for JaCoCo 
                            runtime agent. -->
                        <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <!-- Ensures that the code coverage report for integration tests after 
                    integration tests have been run. -->
                <execution>
                    <id>post-integration-test</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                        <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
                        <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Since you say you are running selenium tests and looking for code coverage, am guessing your intent here is functional code coverage of your application. In that case, have you ensured that your application has been instrumented using jacoco ?

You would need to instrument your application code, have it deployed, run your selenium based functional tests against the instrumented app, and then later pull the report from the instrumented app. I dont think its going to be appearing in your selenium tests side

Comment: thats the idea, I thought from what I had read that the instrumented code would be supplied to cargo plugin. I had made another small change since posting this which was supposed to provide the jacoco arg line to tomcat but I still get no code coverage. Do you know how to get the instrumented code placed into the war file that the cargo plugin is running?